# Displaying all values on sql table

Tags: php

I am trying to display all the user_name from my sql

[image: My sql stuff]

how can i make all the user_name show up with line breaks after each name?"

my code

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$res = mysql_query("SELECT 'user_name' FROM `users`");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo $row;
?>
```

when i load the page nothing shows up

Comment: `select user_name from mytable`?

Comment: Replace `mytable` with whatever your table name is, but sure, that query will get you all the `user_name` entries. Does that really solve your problem?

Comment: just added it and didn't work

Comment: Usually when nothing is shown, this has to do with a false being printed out as nothing. Can you changing `echo $row` to `echo "something awesome: ".$row;`. If you see the "something awesome: " then you know your query doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

This should be all over the internet. A simple google search is all.

```
SELECT user_name FROM users;
```

Make sure you have a connection first:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Do a var_dump($conn); from the file you are showing us here and see what it displays

Comment: After your include at the top, do verbatim this: var_dump($conn); Also, try passing the connection object as  the second parameter of the query. The sql class and functions you are using are deprecated so it's recommended not to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when nothing is shown, this has to do with a false being printed out as nothing. Can you changing echo $row to echo "something awesome: ".$row;. If you see the "something awesome: " then you know your query doesn't return anything.

Second of all, you **don't iterate** thought your results, you just echo one row of the "oh so many".

This can be fixed using a while loop like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM users");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $result['user_name'];
}
```

This will go through each record and echo the username of the users.

Best regards,

Comment: Just tested and the query didn't return anything :(

Comment: I have tried it and nothing returns. I have also tried SELECT `user_name` FROM `users` and nothing returns. I also tried putting the something awesome and still didn't show up.